# Convert a string value from a T-SQL table in float values and store them in a second TSQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I have a TSQL table from which I need to copy a column in a second table. The values that I need to copy are stored in the format 4444.44434 as a string
But first I have to split the String into 4.444,4.4434. Then I store the value in the second table.

Now I do not know exactly how to split the string from the first table and then store them it in the desired format in the second table.

I am very grateful for any solution.

My Code so far:

```
SELECT String, LEN(Matchcode) as Length, 1 as Counter, 0 as Value1 From Test.dbo.tdValue1 
WHILE Counter <> Length { 
String.Index = Length - Counter if ISNUMERIC(String.Index) = 1 
{ LEFT JOIN tdValue1 ON tdValue2.String1 = tdValue1.String; 
Counter += 1 
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I don't know how to read the values exactly either. How do you get from "4444.44434..." to "4.444", exactly? Where's the method here?

Answer (score 0):

Sheesh what a mess. If I understand this correctly you have two values in each row and there is an implied decimal location. I would recommend not storing the "value" but instead storing both values. Each in their own row. Sticking more than 1 piece of data in a single table intersection violates 1NF. I would recommend getting away from a string for storing numbers too.

Here is one way to split this into the two pieces of information using PARSENAME.

```
declare @SomeString varchar(20) = '4444.44434'

select STUFF(PARSENAME(@SomeString, 2), 2, 0, '.')
    , STUFF(PARSENAME(@SomeString, 1), 2, 0, '.')
```